# Allow array (with default value) or null in Symfony 2.1 semantic configuration

Tags: arrays, symfony, symfony-2.1

I need to define an array node with a given default value in a bundle's semantic configuration. This currently looks like:

```
$node->arrayNode('foo')
         ->prototype('scalar')->end()
         ->defaultValue(array('1', '2', '3'))
     ->end();
```

I want to give the user the option to override this array with `null` like:

```
my_bundle:
  foo: ~
```

I cannot use empty arrays (`[]` or `array()`) instead of `null` given that `[]` should have different semantics from `null`.

Is this possible or are there any non-ugly workarounds? Currently I just get an exception:

> InvalidTypeException: Invalid type for path "my_bundle.foo". Expected array, but got NULL

Comment: You defined this as 'scalar' but default value is 'array', should it be array type? Scalar is integer, boolean, string

Comment: The prototype refers to the array's elements.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
$node->arrayNode('foo')
     ->beforeNormalization()
       ->ifTrue(function($v) { return $v === null; })
       ->then(function($v) { return array(); })
     ->end()
     ->prototype('scalar')->end()
     ->defaultValue(array('1', '2', '3'))
 ->end();
```

Or maybe the even simplier:

```
$node->arrayNode('foo')
     ->treatNullLike(array())
     ->prototype('scalar')->end()
     ->defaultValue(array('1', '2', '3'))
 ->end();
```

Otherwise you can use the variableNode rather than the arrayNode; this will give you more freedom but less validation/merging logic out of the box.

Comment: Thanks, but this looks as if I will get `array()` for `null` instead of `null`. I almost suspect that there is no other choice, though. It would probably be hard to express "override with null" vs. empty array in XML, too (not so much for Yaml).

Comment: Yes, that is what is going to happen, but I think that there is no easy escape from this: if you define an arrayNode you will eventually get an array after the configuration has been merged and normalized. You could consider having the foo node as a variableNode otherwise, which will give you more freedom but less validation/merging logic out of the box.

Comment: If you added the variableNode part to the answer, I could accept it, given that I explicitly asked for a way which allows to consider [] different from null. arrayNode does not seem to be an option which fully does what I want.